# Error on xampp running phph code Fatal error spl_autoload_register()

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    $class_name = strtolower($class_name);
    $path = LIB_PATH.DS."{$class_name}.php";
    if(file_exists($path)){
        require_once($path);
    }else{
        die("The file {$class_name}.php could not be found.");
    }
```

> ERROR : Fatal error: __autoload() is no longer supported, use spl_autoload_register() instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\jobportal\include\function.php on line 37

This is the code of a job portal please help I don't understand how to resolve I am new in development new learner if you can help please please.

I am running this on xampp

```
function spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name)  {
    $class_name = strtolower($class_name);
    $path = LIB_PATH.DS."{$class_name}.php";
    if(file_exists($path)){
        require_once($path);
    }else{
        die("The file {$class_name}.php could not be found.");
    }
                
});
```

> ERROR  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "function", expecting variable in C:\xampp\htdocs\jobportal\include\function.php on line 37

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name)  {
    $class_name = strtolower($class_name);
    $path = LIB_PATH.DS."{$class_name}.php";
    if(file_exists($path)){
        require_once($path);
    }else{
        die("The file {$class_name}.php could not be found.");
    }
                
});
```

and when I am not using function keyword then

> ERROR Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_magic_quotes_gpc() in C:\xampp\htdocs\jobportal\include\database.php:15 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\jobportal\include\database.php(132): Database->__construct() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\jobportal\include\accounts.php(2): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\jobportal\include\initialize.php(17): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\jobportal\index.php(2): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\jobportal\include\database.php on line 15

Comment: Please ALWAYS show us ALL the error message not a summary, and not in the title

Comment: Warning
This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0, and REMOVED as of PHP 8.0.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.    https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php          do  this try https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Comment: What version of php are you running..?

Comment: PHP version: 8.1.2

Comment: Is there anything unclear about the error message? As far as I see, it already lists a suggested replacement, so why not use that?

Comment: `Call to undefined function get_magic_quotes_gpc`  - well, that's pretty clear, as that function has been removed from PHP 8, but as that is part of code not listed in your question, it's difficult to provide help

Comment: its not I don't understand what message is showing The issue is if I am changing then I am getting another error and another. Now I have updated the question so it may help. Sorry I am new to this

Comment: Looks like you are running legacy code that is not compatible with PHP 8. Either make it compatible (by resolving one error after the other), or use a compatible PHP version (maybe one of the 7 branch)

Comment: If you need help with this, please share all details in your question without links to external ressources. Also, keep in mind that this is a page for **specific** questions - if you seek help with making a whole application compatible with PHP 8, you should rather contact a freelancer

Comment: @NicoHaase Got it